# How to call the last number input into a column in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 3 different people with 3 different amounts of money. I want them to input their current bank balance in one row and then when their balance updates I want them to put that value in the row beneath. This way I can make a =SPARKLINE of all the values. I also want the sum of all 3 of our current balances however I cannot figure out how to call the last number input into each specific column. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with examples of desired output

Comment: Yes, need a sheet with input data, desired output, and current output.